# How do I SSH to a server starting a bash script that starts a java process, then disconnect from the server without killing the script?

Tags: bash, ssh

So far (not working) my call looks like this:

`ssh -tt -q ${SERVER} "sudo su -l ${USER} -c nohup ${SCRIPT_DIR}/Script.sh start < /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &"`

The meat of the script goes something like this:

```
case "$1" in
'start')
        echo 'Starting server.'
        $JAVA_HOME/java -Xmx1024m -jar myJarFile.jar &
        echo $!>$PID_FILE
        ;;
'stop')
        kill ${cat $PID_FILE}
        ;;
*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start | stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

The stop side works (Slightly different, but start won't work that way either.  I'd guess it works because it's just a quick kill).  I've monkeyed around umpteen different ways on both sides of the equation.  Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No takers, guess I'll just move it to a service so it has its own shell...